# What are the differences between Vitriol, Vituperation, and Invective?

Tags: differences, nouns, synonyms, pejorative-language

I am having a really hard time seeing the nuanced differences between these three synonyms, especially *vituperation* and *vitriol*. I saw from my research that *invective* is used in more formal context with use of refined language (if somebody can add more to this word, I would be appreciate it). But I have trouble seeing the subtle difference between *vitriol* and *vituperation* since both suggest bitter, cruel, harsh abusive language.

Comment: **Vitriol** is a noun and should be used as a noun. **Vituperative** is an adjective and should be used as an adjective. **Invection** is a noun, and, again, should be used as a noun. Unlike vitriol it is **abusive**, and not only harsh or mean.

Comment: @ambitious_ph1lologist **Vituperation** _is_ a noun -- also **invective** is the noun you're looking for.

Comment: Then OP should probably edit the question, because it is confusing: there's **vituperative** in the title and **vituperation** in the body.
EDIT: my first comment has a typo: I meant **invective**

Comment: **Vitriol** is actually an old word for sulphuric acid, used in the metaphorical sense to mean very bitter invective.

Answer (score 2):

*Webster's Dictionary of Synonyms* (1940) covers two of the three words of interest to the question poster—*vituperation* and *invective*—under the general heading of *abuse*; it doesn't discuss *vitriol* at all. Here are the relevant parts of the entry for *abuse*:

> **Abuse, vituperation, invective, obloquy, scurrility, billingsgate** agree in denoting vehemently expressed condemnation or disapproval. ... **Vituperation** suggests the overwhelming of someone or something with a torrent of abuse. "The daily vollies of that that great French master of *vituperation*, Leon Daudet) (*T. S. Eliot*). **Invective** implies vehemence and bitterness in attack or denunciation, and (often in distinction from abuse) connotes a command of language and skill in making one's points. It is the precise term when the attack is public and made in a good cause. "*John Bull* stopped at nothing in the way of insult; but its blazing audacity of *invective* never degenerated into dull abuse." (*A. Repplier*).

The contemporaneous edition of *Webster's Collegiate Dictionary*—the fifth edition (1936)—has this entry for *vitriol*:

> **vitriol** *n.* **1.** *Chem[istry]* **a** A sulphateof any of various metals, as copper (***blue vitriol***) iron (***green vitriol***), zinc (***white vitriol***), etc.;—from the glassy appearance of many of these salts. **b** Oil of vitriol. See SULPHURIC ACID ["A heavy corrosive, oily liquid, H<sub>2</sub>SO<sub>4</sub>, colorless when pure, early made by distilling green vitriol, whence the name *oil of vitriol*"]. **2.** Hence, anything likened to vitriol as being caustic.

So in the 1940s, Merriam-Webster seems to have taken the view that *vituperation* is a kind of tsunami of insult and abuse, while *invective* is a no less bitter but far more considered and selective expression of abuse, as from a notably cultured, cultivated, and articulate enemy. *Vitriol*, meanwhile, in its figurative sense seems not to have advanced very far from its literal origin (in *oil of vitriol*) as a chemical term for sulfuric acid, so its meaning was not broadly "abuse" but something highly corrosive, biting, or acidic.

The synonym notes under abuse in *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) show that MW's view of the difference between *vituperation* and *invective* has changed very little in the six decades since *Webster's Dictionary of Synonyms* appeared:

> VITUPERATION implies fluent and sustained abuse {a torrent of *vituperation*}. INVECTIVE implies a comparable vehemence but suggests greater verbal and rhetorical skill and may apply to a public denunciation {blistering political *invective*}.

The torrent of abuse that MW associated with *vituperation* is still there in the example use of the word, but the flood is now characterized as "fluent and sustained" instead of simply "overwhelming." Meanwhile, *invective* retains the stamp of rhetorical skill and (often) a political cast—although I have trouble making sense of the *Eleventh Collegiate*'s insistence that *invective* "suggests greater verbal and rhetorical skill" than *vituperation*, given that *vituperation* implies "fluent and sustained abuse."

Meanwhile, the *Eleventh Collegiate* has this definition of the figurative sense of *vitriol*:

> **vitriol** ... **2 :** something felt to resemble [chemical] vitriol esp. in caustic quality; *esp* : virulence of feeling or of speech

Neither *vituperation* nor *invective* has the chemical underpinning that *vitriol* does, and neither so clearly frames the character of the abuse or criticism being expressed as caustic or corrosive.

My own sense of *vituperation* and *invective* is that the former suggests true personal bitterness or malignity, while the latter has more of a political cast and thus applies more often in the context of performative outrage—as on the political stage or in the courtroom—than in instances of sincere personal animosity.

Answer (score 0):

After consulting a couple of online resources such as the [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/) and [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/) dictionaries, it seems to me that at least a number of partial answers is available in popular language reference works.

[Here[1]'s](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vituperation) the Merriam-Webster's (MW) take on the small distinctions between **vituperation** and some of its synonyms and words that come close to it in meaning and usage.

As for **vitriol** (which happens to be covered as the last item in the synonym list there) vs. **vituperation**, it seems to me that it may be not so much a matter of precise *meaning* or expression on a factual level as of [***register***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_(sociolinguistics)) or approximative position on a formality scale.

Compare, for a similar case illustrating *register*, the example of some dated subway sign saying

> *Expectoration is forbidden*

to express what could be more plainly put as

> *Please do not spit*

*(Note: Source has eluded me but could be retrievable if needed.)*

For an attempt at a partial seat-of-the-pants answer (another user may be able to give more insight as to this), **vitriol** seems to be rather towards the everyday/colloquial where the more formal and neutral term seems to be **abuse** while **vituperation** seems to me to have a bit of a formal touch for whatever intent or purpose. (Such as the speaker distinctly wishing to sound distinguished and somewhat above any person whose demeanor they may describe as  shedding vitriol.)

Here[2]'s [an example of the use of **vitriol**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/vitriol) from somewhere in literature (last example on the page):

> Two men positioned themselves directly behind me and from them came a constant stream of vitriol.

On a personal note, that lets me think of a street scene of a certainly not elevated tier of society, at least for the two men mentioned. As a matter of taste (YMMV), it seems that here it would be breaking register (in the language of the narration that might credibly be kept in accordance with the content and inner setting of the narration) to use *vituperation*.

So at least part of the matter does boil down to the subtleties of using words of potentially the exact same meaning (depending on context as there are rarely two words of *overall exactly* mutually overlapping content) to express things in one's speech other than just the plain factual meaning, such as mood and register.